# I am an Indian National and have a L1B US visa. Do I require a visa to travel to Philippines?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, philippines

I am an Indian National and have a L1B US visa. Do I require a visa to travel to Philippines? I intend to stay less than 14 days.

Comment: How long do you plan to stay?

Comment: less than 14 days

Answer (score 1):

From the Philippines [Bureau of Immigration](http://www.immigration.gov.ph/index.php/faqs/travel-req):

> B. Indians may be granted a visa-free entry for an initial stay not exceeding 14 days under the Foreign Service Circular No. 36-12, provided, that they possess:
>
> - Unexpired US, Japanese, Australian, Canadian, Schengen, Singapore or UK visa or permanent residence permit;
> - A national passport valid at least six (6) months beyond the contemplated stay;
> - Return or onward ticket to the next country of destination;
> - No Bureau of Immigration (BI), National Intelligence Coordinating Agency (NICA), and the International Police (Interpol) derogatory record.
>
> The 14-day visa-free entry may be extended by an additional seven days for a maximum 21 days.

From the information in your question, it seems that you meet the conditions above, in which case you will not need a visa.